# Access Permissions not reflecting on PDF Document Restriction Summary using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox for PDF encryption. There is a requirement to set all the Document Restriction Summary fields to "Not Allowed". I'm using the below code to set the permissions. But these are not reflecting on PDF Document Restriction Summary.

```
AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
ap.setCanAssembleDocument(false);
ap.setCanExtractContent(false);
ap.setCanExtractForAccessibility(false);
ap.setCanFillInForm(false); 
ap.setCanModify(false); 
ap.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
ap.setCanPrint(false);
ap.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
ap.setReadOnly();
StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(userPassword, globalPassword, ap);   
spp.setPermissions(ap);
spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
pddocument.protect(spp);
pddocument.save(outputpdf);
pddocument.close();
```

[PDF Document Restriction Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BJlG.png)

Comment: What version does the PDF have? Please share it.

Comment: Hi Tilman, we are using pdfbox-2.0.25

Comment: I mean the PDF itself. 1.4, 1.7, which? This is because IIRC low versions don't support all permissions.

Comment: Sorry, PDF Version is showing as 1.3(Acrobat 4.x)

Comment: Then try setting a higher version `PDDocument.setVersion(1.7f)` and use AES256 encryption. (It's hard to understand in the specification, I think it might also work with 1.5)

Comment: Thank you Tilman, I will try to use suggested changes and confirm.